# Lumen home page working but not others on AWS

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, lumen

Im running a Lumen app on Elastic beanstalk
The index (home) page works but non of the others

Base url returns the index page. "Base url + /info" gives me 404

Iv checked the logs and can see nothing mentioned. Iv given the storage folder 777 permissions, also no joy. which is strange since the index page has been cached and is working.

The app works perfectly locally

Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks!

*****EDIT*****

More info:

*public/htaccess*

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

*routes*

```
$router->get('/', 'HomeController@index');
$router->get('info', 'HomeController@info');
```

*HomeController*

```
public function index() {

return view('index');

}

public function info() {

    return view('info');

}
```

Both the index and Info pages extend the app layout page which is located in resources/views/layouts

Comment: Without more context into what isn't working its hard to debug this

Comment: Your right yes. Please see edits above and advise if anything can be added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On an Ngingx server, such as Elastic beanstalk is, the server config has to be edited as described here:
https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.1

In the server array add:

```
location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Comment: hello @Stefanpt, can you pls share how to override the nginx configuration on EBS? I tried to ssh into the server, get the nginx configuration file being used but it's not editable. Another way will be to use .ebextensions (I guess) but how will this be set?